# Missing semicolon in JSONWithPadding

Tags: java, jsonp

The result of JSONWithPadding is missing the semicolon in the end:

```
 JSONWithPadding jsonWithPadding = new JSONWithPadding({"key":"value"}, "cb");
 return Response.status(200).entity(jsonWithPadding).build();
```

Expected:

```
cb({"key":"value"});  --> with semicolon
```

Actual:

```
cb({"key":"value"})  --> without semicolon
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you expect a semicolon? In Javascript the semicolon character is optional in most situations.

Comment: Ho, I didn't knew that it is optional.
What are the situations where it is mandatory?

Comment: The process is called Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI) and is well covered on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi which summarises the points much better than I could write in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon is not missing, it is *optional* in (this example and) most situations. So the `JSONWithPadding` class is working correctly.

The ECMAScript Language Specification defines 7.9.1 [Rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.9.1), summarised from [JavaScript and Semicolons](http://dailyjs.com/2012/04/19/semicolons/) as

> Certain ECMAScript statements (empty statement, variable statement, expression statement, do-while statement, continue statement, break statement, return statement, and throw statement) must be terminated with semicolons

This is also well covered at [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)